# Creating a video from individual frames

Tags: computer-vision, opencv, python

I was able to successfully split a video into it's constituent image frames and analysed them using keras RESNet50 model. I was also able to add the overlays of predictions into these individual images. Now I want to recreate the original video by putting these processed images with overlays back together into an mp4 file.

How can I create a video from individual jpg image frames in sequence?

I am trying to use cv2.VideoWriter to write these images back into a separate video file.

`uname -a` gives me the following output

> Linux myhost 4.15.0-1023-azure #24~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 29
>   12:54:36 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

My first 11 frames are named frame-0000.jpg through frame-0011.jpg

Comment: Please click `edit` under your question and add a list of the names of the first 11 frames. Please also state your Operating System.

Comment: How is `keras` tag valid for this question.?

Comment: It's right there in the description in the very first sentence.

Comment: Your question don't have anything to do with resnet. You are asking how to create video from the images that you have classified with resnet. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I create a video from individual jpg image frames in sequence?

You can use this code for creating video frame by frame from jpg images. These images will be read from folder where this script is.

```
import cv2 #Import of openCV library
import os 
#Create video, with name 'video.mp4', MP4 codec, 60 fps, width 1280 and height of 1024
video = cv2.VideoWriter('video.mp4',cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MP4V'),60,(1280,1024))
for file in os.listdir('./'): #List every file in this folder
    if ".jpg" in file: #Filter only jpg files
        image = cv2.imread(file) #Load image from disk
        video.write(image) #Put image into video.
video.release() #Save video to disk.
```

You can modify this code for loading images from your application or some array.

Edit: added commentary

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. A code-only answer might be useful, but it is a lot more useful if you explain what it does and why it answers the OP's question. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to use `ffmpeg` like this in your Terminal:

```
ffmpeg.exe -f image2 -r 30 -i frame-%04d.jpg -codec:v libx264 -crf 23 video.mp4
```

Comment: So, I guess I'll just write a wrapper around ffmpeg and use it?

Comment: That's what I would do (using Python's `subprocess` module) - but you may have different considerations from me, e.g. like who uses your software and how you need to distribute it.

Comment: Thankfully, no such concerns. Just building a throwaway prototype. Thanks!